# Export textured image as .stl file

Tags: texturing, export

I made a pipe model in blender and now when i add little bit rusted texture inside and try to export as .stl file in order to use in Gazebo, it doesn't appear. Anybody any idea with this?
[image]

Comment: Wikipedia states "STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional object without any representation of color, texture or other common CAD model attributes. " So I am not sure .stl is the right format for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I solved it. Exporting as .obj file to Gazebo solves the issue